# Copying code between Git branches

Tags: git

My project has two branches in the remote server, the master and the release branches. We develop the app on the master branch.

When we make a release, we want to copy the code from the master branch onto the release branch. But I am not able to do it and I need help.

I tried rebasing the code from master to release. Unfortunately, it did not work because some commits had multiple parents.

Cherry pick is not an option because there are too many commits to do it one by one and also it would require to fix conflicts between commits.

Any ideas? how to copy this code between branches? we do need history in the release branch(its already on the master branch)

Edit: Thanks for the quick answers. Unfortunately, Gerrit does not allow mergers and rejects my pushes with mergers

Comment: http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging

Comment: what about simply merging the branch?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think simply using `git merge` will be enough.

```
git checkout production
git merge master
```

Comment: @user2485710, you should only do a `git fetch` if remotes are involved, which were not mentioned at all...